# Loop through object whose key's values are arrays (the values of which are objects)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Unfortunately my question was closed yesterday - I read through his answer but I'm still stuck. I have learnt a bit more about it but can't seem to get it right. I have some crazy multidimensional madness going on and it's confusing the hell out of me!

fresh_posts.php:

```
{ 
    "posts":{
        "5": {
            "id":"5",
            "image":"link.jpg",
            "submitter":"4322309",
            "views":"3"
        },
        "2": {
            "id":"2",
            "image":"link.jpg",
            "submitter":"4322309",
            "views":"5"
        }
    },

    "comments":{
        "2": [{
            "id":"1",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"2"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"2"
        }
    ],
        "5": [{
            "id":"3",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"5"
        }]
    }
}
```

Initially, I do:

```
$.getJSON('fresh_posts.php',function(data){
    global_save_json = data.comments; // saves comments object for later use
    ... 
})
```

I then use it later (outside of `getJSON`) inside a click function.

```
$('.main').on('click','.new-comments',function(e){

    var fullid = e.target.id;
    var subid = fullid.substring(8); // subid = the number of string e.g. "show-all88" from fullid becomes "88" from subid.

    function appendAllComments(input){

        $.each(global_save_json.input,function(index,value){
            for (var key in value) {
                if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(key + " -> " + value[key]);
                }
            }
        })

    }

    appendAllComments(subid);

})
```

• Let's say we send input `2` though (in example JSON object above), and I need to loop through that array (each value of that array containing an object). So we do (?):

```
$.each(global_save_json.2,function(index,value){
```

or is it

```
$.each(global_save_json."2",function(index,value){
```

^ We are looping through each value in the array (?)

• Then, for each object (values of each array are objects):

```
for (var key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + value[key]);
    }
}
```

From the `$.each()` loop above, we defined the array value as "value", so now when we loop the object "value", right?

None of this seems to be working, or throws errors all the time (currently `cannot read property 'length' of undefined`), so I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: To get the comments associated with post 2, you do `global_save_json['2']` (quotes are optional). So, neither of the two syntaxes you tried. Then, the function you have, looping over `var key in value` should log all the key-val pairs for each comment object.

Comment: Is `input` defined at `global_save_json.input` ?

Comment: Good catch @guest271314. In `$.each(global_save_json.input,...`, you probably don't want that `.input` since `global_save_json` is the `data.comments` array.

Comment: @Ahmed, wow that seemed to solve it completely by just doing `global_save_json[input]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, glad you figured it out, here's my official answer:

The `obj.key` syntax is equivalent to `obj['key']` and is useful if the key you're indexing is literal. But when you want to programmatically look up a key, the latter syntax is the only one you can use, since you can do `var input = 2; obj[input]`. (In JavaScript, all keys are strings, so it doesn't matter whether `input = 2` or `input = '2'`, when the runtime sees `obj[input]`, it'll coerce `input` to string.) There's no way to use the dot syntax with a variable that stores the key name.

With all that said, you can never use numerical values as keys with the dot syntax. With arrays and objects with numerical keys (technically, JS arrays are objects so this distinction is hyperfine…), you can't ever do `obj.2` or `arr.0`, you use the bracket syntax: `obj[2]` or `arr[0]`.

Just a tip: it's really helpful to play with a JavaScript console when you're trying to figure out how to slice and dice this kind of deeply-nested objects. You can copy the JSON data at the top of your post, [open your JS console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337), type in `var data = <PASTE>`. This works because JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" and is valid JavaScript! Then, you can type in `data.comments.2` and see that it's a syntax error, and similarly with `data.comments.'2'`. But `data.comments[2]` gives you two objects, and so you can then run `data.comments[2].map(function(val, idx) {return val.comment})` to make sure you got the syntax.

(If you do a lot with JS objects and arrays and data, I recommend [lodash](https://lodash.com) or similar projects like [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/) and [Trine](http://jussi-kalliokoski.github.io/trine/).)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go two times throug

```
for (var key in obj) {
    //Get posts and comments
    var objectsInner = obj[key];

    for (var key2 in objectsInner) {
        //This is arrays in posts and comments
        // key2 has values '2' and '5', and inside these objects you have an array
        var arrays = objectsInner[key2];
    }
}
```

and you can create a function to retrieve all data based on input ('2')
take a look in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ldk9spne/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var posts = data.posts;
var comments = data.comments;

// Cycle for posts
for(var id in posts) {
    // Get comments for post
    if (comments[id] !== undefined) {
        comments[id].forEach(function(c){
            console.log('Comment '+ c.id +' for post ' + id +', made by '+ c.submitter +': ' + c.comment);
        });
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/pacuqetita/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you treat posts and comments differently, because both are different in data. Please try something like this

```js
$.each(data,function(key, postsOrComments){
 if (key == 'posts') {
  $.each(postsOrComments, function(index, post) { 
   console.log(post);
  });
 } else if (key == 'comments') {
  $.each(postsOrComments, function(index, comments) { 
   $.each(comments, function(index, comment) { 
    console.log(comment);
   });
  });
 }
});``
```

data variable must be your ajax output.

Comment: I have solved it now, Ahmed in the comment above provided the simplest solution possible, using `global_save_json[input]` instead of `global_save_json.input` - although I'm not sure why that works? Anyway, I didn't end up needing the for loop for the objects and instead only needed that first `$.each` loop to do what I wanted.